# NGINX Image not found

Tags: html, nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to make custom 404 page.

Here is my 404.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="...">
      <div style="...">404</div>
      <div style="...">Page not found</div>
      <img src="404.gif" alt="not found" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it works (almost), but I always get "Not found" error trying to load 404.gif

Here is my nginx config (*want to make only `localhost/main/data` and `localhost/main/test` paths available*):

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
      root /var/www/error/;
    }

    location /404.gif {
      root /var/www/error/;
    }

    location ~ ^/main/(data|test)$ {
    }
```

When I'm trying to reach any page like `http://localhost/main/error_page` server returns custom 404 page without gif and error `GET http://localhost/main/404.gif 404 (Not Found)`.

How to load my gif, what path I need to provide in html or how to change config?

Comment: check error in `/var/log/nginx/errors.log`, it will tell you where its trying to fetch image from, start debugging from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to redirect any request of this gif like this

```
location ~* /(.*)404.gif$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /404.gif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the correct image path in image tag src

```
<img src="../somefolder/somefoler/404.gif" alt="not found" />
```